# You can't specify target table 'Employee' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

```
delete from Employee where Salary=(select max(Salary) from Employee)
```

why is error is showing. can someone help me how to solve it with logic.

Comment: Please always search for your error using your favourite search engine before asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE t1.*
FROM Employee t1
JOIN (SELECT MAX(Salary) Salary FROM Employee) t2
where t1.Salary = t2.Salary
```